# How to parallelize python processes in Windows cmd when using a virtual environment

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, virtualenv

I want to run some python processes in parallel. This is what I have in my bat/cmd file:

```
call venv\Scripts\activate

python proc1.py

(
start "Process 2" /b cmd /c python proc2.py
start "Process 3" /b cmd /c python proc3.py
)
```

If I run that as a batch, proc1.py will run without a problem, but proc2.py and proc3.py will be aborted because of a missing module, which is nevertheless installed in the virtual environment. My hunch is that for somehow within the parentheses, the python that is used is not the venv one.

Thus, I also tried it this way:

```
(
start "Process 2" /b cmd /c call venv\Scripts\activate && python proc2.py
start "Process 3" /b cmd /c call venv\Scripts\activate && python proc3.py
)
```

The result is nevertheless the same. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: The issue seems more related to you specifically starting new cmd.exe processes, have you tried it without invoking those? e.g. `call activate`, `python proc1.py`, `start python proc2.py`, `start python proc3.py`.

Comment: Indeed, early on I tried that, but it just seemed to ignore the command. I mean that it ran through without starting the process. Then I found a SO post that suggested using cmd in between, and then getting an error message seemed like a step forward.

Comment: Wait a minute. Doing this without the parentheses works. But the problem is now that I need to group processes so that some of them start only after some previous have finished.

Comment: If you want standard executables to run without waiting for completion, use `start` otherwise don't.